# Upper bound for truncated Taylor series of $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone provide a hint as to how we could prove the following inequality?

$$\left|~e^x - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}~\right| \leq \frac{|x|^n e^{|x|}}{ n!}$$

The series looks like a truncated Taylor series for $e^x$ but I'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: See [Lagrange's remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder). As the $n$th derivative of $e^t$ is itself, and the maximum value of it on $[-|x|,|x|]$ occurs at $t=|x|$, the error is bounded by $e^{|x|}|x|^n/n!$.

Answer (score 1):

Imported from comments:

---

See [Lagrange's remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder). As the $n$th derivative of $e^t $is itself, and the maximum value of it on $[−|x|,|x|]$ occurs at $t=|x|$, the error is bounded by $e^{|x|}|x|^n/n!$.